# Counting the items in a 2-column Excel named range with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I'm prototyping something with Excel and I've hit a bump.  I can easily solve it using the language I'll eventually write it in but I don't know how to do it in Excel and I need to finish the prototype.

The basic problem is that I need Excel to look at columns A & B as a single 2-column list instead of two separate columns.  I want the counts for just the subset symbols when paired with just the subset indicators.  How can I make Excel look at columns A & B as a single list that requires each cell in a list row be matched to both the indicator and symbol sublists to be counted?  Click on the picture for more details.

I've tried variations of COUNTIFS() but it wants a single criteria for each comparison.  I haven't found a way to use a named range containing the list of data to be compared.  I'd like to say, "Look in named range ColAB, and for each row, if the indicator is in the named range ColH and the symbol is in the named range ColD then add one to the count."

I've programmed in multiple languages, including VB, but haven't ever used Excel macros so I'm not sure how to start with that.  After the prototyping is done I'll probably implement my daily solution using bash shell scripts on text files with results.  What I want to do here will be easy to do there but I want to have a complete Excel prototype before I go in that direction. [Screenshot of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fytad.png)

Comment: Not sure why you've struggled to implement a set-up with `COUNTIFS`: the formula in `E2`, for example, would be `=SUM(COUNTIFS(ColB,D2,ColA,ColH))` (replace `SUM` with `SUMPRODUCT` if you're using a pre-O365 version of Excel).

Comment: Just curious, so what is the expected result in cell F1 and J11, as there is "Weed3" in cell A16 and "ORIC" in cell B16 ?

Comment: Can't you just concatenate A&B together? https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-vba-to-concatenate-two-columns.356525/

Comment: E2 is already handled.  I was looking for the highlighted columns, F and J.  Also, not sure how concatenating A&B would help search since E and I aren't concatenated.  Problem has been solved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the column named ranges I created it looks like this.

Symbol count in F:

```
=SUM((ColB=D2)*(ColA=TRANSPOSE(ColH)))
```

Indicator count in J:

```
=SUM((ColB=TRANSPOSE(ColD))*(ColA=H2))
```

D2 becomes D3, D4, etc. for each row.  H2 becomes H3, H4, etc.